# Android Custom Dialog Fragment callback not being called

Tags: android, callback, android-dialogfragment

So in my app i'm in need of using several confirmation dialogFragments of the same type, basically, it has a message, yes/no and a callback for the positive message. I managed to do it, except for the callback part, which i cant figure it out why it is not being called. Any help would be appreciated. Thx.

```
    public class MessageDialogFragment2 extends DialogFragment {


     * Config DialogFrag
     */
    private static String title = "";
    private static String message = "";
    private static String positiveButtonValue = "";
    private static String negativeButtonValue = "";

    private static MessageDialogFragment2 myDialog;

    public static void newInstance() {
        myDialog =  new MessageDialogFragment2();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        // request a window without the title
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.exit_dialog_fragment, container, false);
        setCancelable(false);
        return v;
    }

    private static void showDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String dialogId){
        myDialog.show(fragmentManager, dialogId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
//
//        setValues();
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.positiveButton, R.id.negativeButton})
    public void exit(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.positiveButton:

                break;

            case R.id.negativeButton:
                MessageDialogFragment2.this.dismiss();
               break;
        }
    }

    public static class MakeDialog{
        private Activity activity;
        private PositiveCallback positiveCallBack;
        private NegativeCallback negativeCallBack;

        public MakeDialog(Activity act){
            this.activity = act;
            newInstance();
        }

        public MakeDialog setTitle(String title2){
            title = title2;
            return this;
        }

        public MakeDialog setMessage(String message2){
            message = message2;
            return this;
        }

        public MakeDialog setPositiveButtonMessage(String message){
            positiveButtonValue = message;
            return this;
        }

        public MakeDialog setNegativeButtonMessage(String message){
            negativeButtonValue = message;
            return this;
        }

        public void show(){
            showDialog(activity.getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_ID);
        }

        public MakeDialog setPositiveCallBack(PositiveCallback pcb){
            this.positiveCallBack = pcb;
            return this;
        }

        public MakeDialog setNegativeCallBack(NegativeCallback ncb){
            this.negativeCallBack = ncb;
            return this;
        }

        public interface PositiveCallback {
            public void doPositiveCallback();
        }
        public interface NegativeCallback {
            public void doNegativeCallback();
        }
    }



}
```

Calling it like this:

```
 new MessageDialogFragment2.MakeDialog(this)
                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_title))
                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_message))
                .setPositiveButtonMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.yes))
                .setNegativeButtonMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no))
                .setPositiveCallBack(new MessageDialogFragment2.MakeDialog.PositiveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void doPositiveCallback() {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Expected result: doSomething() gets called

Actual result: doSomething() not being called.

PS: Any problem detected in the code not question related can be pointed out. I'm always up for improving my knowledge and write better code!

Comment: pfff can't believe how stupied i am :p i already know the answer. Will do a proper answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, there was something missing. I was not calling the callback inside my DialogFragment class!

```
@OnClick({R.id.positiveButton, R.id.negativeButton})
public void exit(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.positiveButton:
            if(positiveCallBack == null)
                MessageDialogFragment2.this.dismiss();
            else
                positiveCallBack.doPositiveCallback();
            break;

        case R.id.negativeButton:
            if(negativeCallBack == null)
                MessageDialogFragment2.this.dismiss();
            else
                negativeCallBack.doNegativeCallback();
           break;
    }
}
```